# Application detected as malware

Tags: malware, false-positive

I've recently joined a team which worked back in 2008-2009 in a game project. The game is still running, however, it's detected by few antivirus providers as a malware. At first I thought sending them an email asking for the reason it got detected would've been the best thing to do, but gmail won't allow me to upload the file since it also detects it as malware. I even tried to send a zipped archive with the app in it but it hasn't changed anything.
Does anyone have a suggestion on what to do? I just want to identify the reason why the application gets detected to check whether the game is a virus or a false positive, and in this case edit the code (which I have at disposal, but note that it's very confusing since it's an old software).
Thank you for your time.

Edit: Uploaded a screenshot of the scan with virustotal.com.[image]

Comment: Have you tried uploading the app to e.g. Virustotal to see what it's detected as?

Comment: Yes, I can post the result if needed.

Comment: I might imagine a PUA ("Potentially Unwanted Application") thing could be triggered by e.g. a downloader component in the app...

Comment: Well the application is built so that whenever there's an update the installer updates the application in the AppData folder. Do you think it might be the cause? An old installer not following the most recent policies?

Comment: I'd imagine that's possible, but of course it's hard to say for certain :)

Comment: Do you know any other way to send an email with the infected file to each company since gmail is blocking me? I guess the only ones being able to tell me what's wrong are the companies involved.

Comment: Maybe a file share like wetransfer.com, or an encrypted ZIP file that you supply the password to in the email?